# Borrow checker error in a loop inside a recursive function with lifetime bounds

Tags: loops, recursion, rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

Why does the borrow checker complain about this code?

```
fn foo<'a>(v: &mut Vec<&'a str>, buf: &'a mut String) {
    loop {
        foo(v, buf);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*buf` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/main.rs:3:16
  |
3 |         foo(v, buf);
  |                ^^^ mutable borrow starts here in previous iteration of loop
4 |     }
5 | }
  | - mutable borrow ends here
```

If I remove the lifetime bound, the code compiles fine.

```
fn foo(v: &mut Vec<&str>, buf: &mut String) {
    loop {
        foo(v, buf);
    }
}
```

This isn't a duplicate of [Mutable borrow in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50111949/mutable-borrow-in-a-loop), because there is no return value in my case.

---

I'm pretty sure that my final goal isn't achievable in safe Rust, but right now I want to better understand how the borrow checker works and I can not understand why adding a lifetime bound between parameters extends the lifetime of the borrow in this code.

Comment: Sorry for awful title, but I have no clue how to describe the problem in other words. Looks like all of this conditions are required to reproduce this error.

Comment: Actually this is a bit weird. But it's not about recursion. If you call another function with the same type signature, you'll have the same problem.

Comment: As a hint, consider that it works with no lifetimes, and remember that the elided lifetimes are treated as all distinct within the function arguments. So without the lifetime annotations it's the same as `fn foo<'a, 'b, 'c>(v: &'a mut Vec<&'b str>, buf: &'c mut String)`. The difference with your version that doesn't work is that you have re-used a lifetime for two of the arguments, tying them together. Neither of them can outlive the other.

Comment: @PeterHall thank you for an advise, but in real function I need them to be bound. Actually lifetime sybtyping is enough, but in this example I made them equal for simplicity.

Comment: Then perhaps you should add a bit more information about what you are trying to accomplish. The lifetimes, as you have specified them, won't work. But some other ones might

Comment: At a guess, I'd say that you are taking slices from `buf` and storing them in `v`. Is that the case? If so, you may not be able to keep all those references mutable.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm pretty sure that my final goal isn't achievable in safe rust, but right now I want to better understand how borrowck works and I can not understand why adding lifetime bound between parameters extends lifetime of `buf` in this code.

Comment: But there could be workarounds, such as using an `Rc<String>` for the buf instead of the `&mut String`. Really depends on what you are _really_ trying to do here.

Comment: If you do need `buf` to be mutable, you'll never get this to work because mutating the string could invalidate the string slices stored in `v` if the string needs to reallocate its storage. If you don't need `buf` to be mutable, then change `&'a mut String` to `&'a str` and it'll just work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version with the explicit lifetime `'a` ties the lifetime of the `Vec` to the lifetime of `buf`. This causes trouble when the `Vec` and the `String` are reborrowed. Reborrowing occurs when the arguments are passed to `foo` in the loop:

```
fn foo<'a>(v: &mut Vec<&'a str>, buf: &'a mut String) {
    loop {
        foo(&mut *v, &mut *buf);
    }
}
```

This is done implicitly by the compiler to prevent the arguments from being consumed when `foo` is called in the loop. If the arguments were actually moved, they could not be used anymore (e.g. for successive calls to `foo`) after the first recursive call to `foo`.

Forcing `buf` to be moved around resolves the error:

```
fn foo<'a>(v: &mut Vec<&'a str>, buf: &'a mut String) {
    foo_recursive(v, buf);
}

fn foo_recursive<'a>(v: &mut Vec<&'a str>, buf: &'a mut String) -> &'a mut String{
    let mut buf_temp = buf;
    loop {
        let buf_loop = buf_temp;
        buf_temp = foo_recursive(v, buf_loop);
        // some break condition
    }
    buf_temp
}
```

However, things will break again as soon as you try to actually use `buf`. Here is a distilled version of your example demonstrating why the compiler forbids successive mutable borrows of `buf`:

```
fn foo<'a>(v: &mut Vec<&'a str>, buf: &'a mut String) {
    bar(v, buf);
    bar(v, buf);
}

fn bar<'a>(v: &mut Vec<&'a str>, buf: &'a mut String) {
    if v.is_empty() {
        // first call: push slice referencing "A" into 'v'
        v.push(&buf[0..1]);
    } else {
        // second call: remove "A" while 'v' is still holding a reference to it - not allowed
        buf.clear();
    }
}

fn main() {
    foo(&mut vec![], &mut String::from("A"));
}
```

The calls to `bar` are the equivalents to the recursive calls to `foo` in your example. Again the compiler complains that `*buf` cannot be borrowed as mutable more than once at a time. The provided implementation of `bar` shows that the lifetime specification on `bar` would allow this function to be implemented in such a way that `v` enters an invalid state. The compiler understands by looking at the signature of `bar` alone that data from `buf` could potentially flow into `v` and rejects the code as potentially unsafe regardless of the actual implementation of `bar`.